# Power automate, copy items from online excel to list, only a certain amount of items

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, power-automate, flow, power-platform

How come my flow is only creating a certain amount of items?

I am trying to copy from my table (online excel) to a list.

Would there ever be a reason to only copying over 255 items? I have checked I have no filters.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default List rows action in excel connector only returns 256 items.

You can get more rows returned by setting a higher value for the pagination settings.

1. Go to "List rows present in table" action
2. Select the options elipses ("...")
3. Select 'Settings'
4. Enable Pagination
5. Set an appropriate row limit

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks, what if i have blank rows in my table?

Comment: What about it? If you don't want to create an item in case of blank row/column, you can add condition based respective required column inside "Apply to each". Create item only when that column is not empty.